# Maximum of multiple files without considering missing values using awk

Tags: shell, awk, max

I want to calculate the maximum of 15 files:- ifile1.txt, ifile2.txt, ....., ifile15.txt. Number of columns and rows of each file are same. But some of them are missing values. Part of the data looks as

```
 ifile1.txt      ifile2.txt       ifile3.txt
 3  ?  ?  ? .    1  2  1  3 .    4  ?  ?  ? .
 1  ?  ?  ? .    1  ?  ?  ? .    5  ?  ?  ? .
 4  6  5  2 .    2  5  5  1 .    3  4  3  1 .
 5  5  7  1 .    0  0  1  1 .    4  3  4  0 .
 .  .  .  . .    .  .  .  . .    .  .  .  . .
```

I would like write maximums of these 15 files without considering the missing values.

```
 ofile.txt
 4   2  1  3  . (i.e. max of 3 1 4, max of ? 2 ? and so on)
 5   ?  ?  ?  .
 4   6  5  2  .
 5   5  7  4  .
 .   .  .  .  .
```

I am trying with this, but not getting the result.

```
awk '
  {
   for( i = 1; i <= FNR; i++){
      for( j = 1; j <= NF; j++) printf "%s ", {
    max=="" || $i > max {max=$i} END{ print max}' FS="|" : "?"
      print ""
      }
   }
' ifile*
```

Comment: By putting those `.`s in your sample input and output you've created work for us as we'd then have to remove those dots to create something we could test a possible solution against. Don't do that - make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Comment: Many thanks @EdMorton .. I was not aware of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `awk` program:

```
awk '{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    if($i>a[FNR,i] && $i!="?")
      a[FNR,i]=$i
}
END{
  for(j=1;j<=FNR;j++)
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
      printf "%s%s",(a[j,i]?a[j,i]:"?"),(i<NF?OFS:ORS)
}' file1 file2 file3
4 2 1 3
5 ? ? ?
4 6 5 2
5 5 7 1
```

The default loop will get values from all files and store the highest value into the array `a`.

The `END` statement is looping through the array to display the values.

This relies on `FNR`, the line number of the current file being processed and `NF` the number of fields of the current line.

Comment: `a[i,j]?a[i,j]:"?"` should be `(i,j) in a?a[i,j]:"?"`. As written you'll change a value of `0` to `?`. You should always put parens around your ternary expressions btw as they'r produce syntax errors in some contexts with some awks otherwise - `((i,j) in a ? a[i,j] : ?")`.

Comment: Also as written you'll add a blank char to the end of each line which is always undesirable. Just test for the last field and add the appropriate character and also use ORS instead of hard-coding the value you THINK ORS will have (`"\n"`). So instead of those last 2 printf lines you should actually replace them both with just this 1 line: `printf "%s%s", ((i,j) in a ? a[i,j] : "?"), (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)`. Wish you'd used `i` consistently for the field number btw - having it be the field number when populating the array and then the line number when accessing it obfuscates the code.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks a lot for these comments. I fully agree with your 2nd comment. I would also agree on the 1st one, but in this case I keep the test on the array content rather that on the array indexes (`(i,j) in a`). For the some reason the `if` in the main loop is assigning the indexes, making the printing incorrect. Weird `awk` behavior to me that I could reproduce with `awk 'BEGIN{if(a[1,1]<1) print "fail"; if(a[1,1]) print "fail"; }'`

Comment: Ah, right. `$i>a[FNR,i]` is creating `a[FNR,i] = zero-or-null` - given that change your later test  from `a[FNR,i]` to `a[FNR,i] != ""` to differentiate that case from the case where you populate it with `0` from the input.

Answer (score 1):

Taking some memory but only 1 loop per file

```
awk '{L=FNR==1?"":L ORS;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){R=FNR":"i; M[R]=M[R]*1<=$i*1?$i:M[R];L=L OFS M[R]}}END{print L}' ifile*
```

explain:

```
awk '{
   #Lines output buffer is reset on first line of file and append with new line otherwise
   L=FNR==1?"":L ORS
   # for every field (number in line)
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
      # create a index reference (line + field) 
      R=FNR":"i
      # set in an array the max value between old value for this reference and current one. the ( * 1 ) allow to compare ? and number but only used in compare values, not assignation to keep the "?"
      M[R]=M[R]*1<=$i*1?$i:M[R]
      # Append the value to Output lines
      L=L OFS M[R]}}

  # after last line of last file, print the Output lines
  END{print L}
  ' ifile*
```